# how to run docker build command in jenkins shell prompt

Tags: docker, jenkins

I want to run docker build command in Jenkins shell prompt.

Have already installed docker and add Jenkins user in docker usergroup.

But when i hit docker build command it shows me permission denied issue  and when i am using sudo prefix it ask for password with -S argument.

I am running all commands on Jenkins master, earlier i used on other node server not master.

[image: error]

So what is best way to resolve this.

Comment: Are you running it on-prem or cloud?

Comment: My jenkins running on aws ec2.